# java.lang.NullPointer Exception (TestNG)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a class "BaseTest" class where web driver-related code resides and all the BeforeTest & AfterTest methods. I've extended this method in the 'Login' file and 'SkillsAcquisition' file,  but only the login file runs fine and I get NullPointer exception in the second file. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

I am new to Selenium and testng so any help is hugely appreciated.

`BaseTest.java`

```
package Students;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class BaseTest {

    String driverPath = "my_path_to_chromedriver";
    public String baseUrl = "some_url";

    public WebDriver driver ; 
    public String expected = null;
    public String actual = null;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert;
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void launchBrowser() {
        System.out.println("launching Chrome browser"); 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
        driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
    }
    
    @AfterTest
    public void terminateBrowser(){
        driver.close();
    }
    
    private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
        try {
          driver.findElement(by);
          return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      private boolean isAlertPresent() {
        try {
          driver.switchTo().alert();
          return true;
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
        try {
          Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
          String alertText = alert.getText();
          if (acceptNextAlert) {
            alert.accept();
          } else {
            alert.dismiss();
          }
          return alertText;
        } finally {
          acceptNextAlert = true;
        }
      }

}
```

`Login.java`

```
package Students;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Login extends BaseTest{
    
        @Test(priority = 0)
        public void login() throws InterruptedException{
            driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).sendKeys("my_username");
            driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("my_password");
            driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
            expected = "Expected Text";
            actual = driver.getTitle();
            Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);  
    }
}
```

`SkillsAcquisition.java`

```
package Students;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

@Test
public class SkillsAcquisition extends BaseTest{

        @Test(priority = 1)
        public void addSkills() throws InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("Test reached Second file");
            WebDriverWait d = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);            
d.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("skillAquistionTab")));
            driver.findElement(By.id("skillAquistionTab")).click();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            d.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//a[@class='add']")));
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='add']")).click();      
            System.out.println("Added");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'])[2]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'])[2]")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'])[2]")).sendKeys("Skill1");
            driver.findElement(By.id("page-wrapper-1")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Skill1")).click();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("addProgramButton")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("ProgramName")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("ProgramName")).sendKeys("Program1");
            driver.findElement(By.id("SaveNewProgram")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            String Newprogramname = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Program1")).getText();
            String createdprogramName = "Program1";
            Assert.assertEquals(Newprogramname,createdprogramName);
            System.out.println("Program created sucessfully");
        }   
    }
```

`Testng.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="Students.Login"/>
      <class name="Students.SkillsAcquisition"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

Screenshot of the error.
[click to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SyrO.png)

Comment: It looks like your driver is null. 
From counting your lines (line 33) of SkillsAcquisition, it looks like one of these two lines has the exception
`
WebDriverWait d = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);            
d.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("skillAquistionTab")));
`

Comment: Yeah, `driver` is null, the stack trace points to the constructor of `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: Shouldn't it pull driver properties from the BaseTest.java class? If not, please assist how I can resolve this error. I added driver properties to this file, and yet it errors out with the same error message. @Smutje

Comment: Quick solution - in your base create a method for `getDriver()` which does: `returns driver;`  - then, at don't call driver directly, call getDriver instead.   There may be other ways but with so many lines of code it's difficult. For the best chance at a bespoke answer can i please suggest you follow this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks, @RichEdwards for the advice. I added return type method that returns driver but seems it didn't do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `@BeforeTest` to `@BeforeMethod`. Before test is executed once for a `test` tag in your `testng.xml`. This is why your first test passes but the second fails.

Another option (just FYI but I am sure this is not what you need) is to change your `testng.xml` to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test1">
    <classes>
      <class name="Students.Login"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test2">
    <classes>
      <class name="Students.SkillsAcquisition"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

Since here you have own `test` tag for each of your test classes, your tests will pass.
Since here you have own `test` tag for each of your test cla

Comment: Thanks, @Alexey R. for the suggestion. I tried both your methods, I do see that the web driver is working as expected but it fires up a new browser for each test in both methods. For instance, it starts one browser, runs the login test, and again fires up another browser to run the second file. Since the second file doesn't have anything related to login, the test just errors out.

Comment: Of course you need to apply some design skills to make your code consistent. TestNg itself does not give you the answers because it does not now anything about the logic of your tests. You can add some specific `@BeforeMethod` to your non-login class that would be responsible for log.